# jQuery keydown event in cakePHP

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I need to write a keydown event that will catch the characters entered in the specified input field. I need to do this using jQuery in cakePHP.

And i need this function to work in general for all the input text fields in a form. Please tell me where to place the code? And how to code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like this which binds keydown event to all input elements with type text which are inside the form with id `yourformid`.

```
$(function(){
    $("#yourformid input:text").bind("keydown", function(){
         var currentElemID = this.id;
         //if you want to convert the current element to a jQuery object then you can use $(this)
    });
});
```

Comment: @rahul , asking casually , out of context question , what do you do ??

Comment: @gov Given nearly 1700 answers, I would say *this* mainly. ;-)

Comment: Thanks rahul. Also, is there a way to get the ID of the input field in which the key was pressed? ie, the keypress event should be a general function which can get the id of the field and based on that id it should do the code!

Comment: @phoenix you should get it by this.id

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion. Always use unobtrusive JavaScript techniques. they are maintainable an also pretty more thin. In my personal experience I have had lots of trouble by using Rails with JavaScript code in the controllers. The same must apply for CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jquery's [`keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) like:

```
$("#field").keypress(function(event){ var code = event.which});
```

variable code will be the character's ascii number, then if you'd like, you can convert using the native function [`fromCharCode()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp)

*Things to note:  IE will not detect backspace using keypress, only on keydown and keyup.*

Comment: Thanks barbiker. Also, is there a way to get the ID of the input field in which the key was pressed? ie, the keypress event should be a general function which can get the id of the field and based on that id it should do the code!